# NestedScrollView inside of a ConstraintLayout: sizing the scroll view to the content or allowing it to scroll

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a layout which has:

```
CoordinatorLayout (For Bottom Sheet animations)
.. MaterialCardView (Bottom Sheet)
.... ConstraintLayout
...... (header views)
...... NestedScrollView
........ ConstraintLayout
.......... (some other views which fit on some devices but are too large on smaller devices)
```

On a large device the entire layout looks like this once the bottom sheet is expanded
[image: large expanded]

Notice "top of scroll" and "bottom of scroll" showing the top and bottom of the `NestedScrollView`

On a large device it looks exactly how I want it

- there is not extra blank space at the bottom
- the entire view is visible

On a smaller device I wind up with something [demonstrated in this gif](https://gfycat.com/shabbypolitegalapagosalbatross)

On the plus side the scroll view is able to scroll fine however it seems that the view has become too large to actually fit on the screen so I can't see all of the scroll view content.

What I ultimately want:

- don't show extra whitespace if the entire `NestedScrollView` can be shown on screen
- on smaller devices allow the area to scroll such that it is all visible

Current Layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/sheet"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="200dp"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
        tools:behavior_peekHeight="400dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/hello"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello"
                android:textSize="48sp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/world"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="World"
                android:textSize="48sp"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/hello" />

            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/world">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/top_scroll"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="top of scroll"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/one"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:background="#caf"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_scroll" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/two"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:background="#cab"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/one" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/three"
                        android:layout_width="300dp"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:background="#ca4"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/two" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/bottom_scroll"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="bottom of scroll"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/three" />


                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I suspect something is wrong with the `NestedScrollView` constraints as I had to add a bias to prevent it from overlapping with the views above it - as if it is too big (which is reflected in the small device gif).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution I came up with:

Wrap the header views and `NestedScrollView` in a LinearLayout and give the `NestedScrollView` a weight of 1.

The final layout looks like:

```
CoordinatorLayout (For Bottom Sheet animations)
.. MaterialCardView (Bottom Sheet)
.... LinearLayout
...... ConstraintLayout
........ (header views)
...... NestedScrollView
........ ConstraintLayout
.......... (some other views which fit on some devices but are too large on smaller devices)
```

And the working XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="200dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
        tools:behavior_peekHeight="400dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/hello"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Hello"
                    android:textSize="48sp"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/world"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="World"
                    android:textSize="48sp"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/hello" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/top_scroll"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="top of scroll"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/one"
                        android:layout_width="200dp"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:background="#caf"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_scroll" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/two"
                        android:layout_width="80dp"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:background="#cab"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/one" />

                    <View
                        android:id="@+id/three"
                        android:layout_width="300dp"
                        android:layout_height="200dp"
                        android:background="#ca4"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/two" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/bottom_scroll"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="bottom of scroll"
                        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/three" />


                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```